# Single Function is Called Depending on Clicked Button

Tags: actionscript-3

I am looking to have a single function that removes listeners based on the switch/case button that was clicked. I have 2 MCs on the stage named "btn01" and "btn02" and have an array with matching names.

I want `btnRemove()` to be able to `removeListener` to `btn01` if it was click, or if `btn02` was clicked. How do I accomplish this? Thanks.

```
var buttons = new Array(btn01, btn02);

for (var a=0; a<buttons.length; a++){
    buttons[a].buttonMode=true;
    buttons[a].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonClick);
}

function btnRemove() {
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonClick); //1120: Access of undefined property e
}

function buttonClick(e:Event):void{
switch(e.currentTarget.name){

    case "btn01":

    btnRemove(); //remove btn01 listener

    break;

    case "btn02":

    btnRemove(); //remove btn02 listener

    break;
}}
```

Comment: just do `e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(...`  - or `btnRemove(e.currentTarget)` then `function btnRemove(obj){ obj.removeEventListener(...)`

Comment: That's originally what I've done, but I get errors 1120 and 1137 regarding property e being undefined and incorrect number of arguments.

Comment: in your edited question, the error is because `e` only exists in the `buttonClick` function.  You would have to change your `btnRemove` function so it accepts an argument, then inside buttonClick pass `e.currentTarget` as the argument.  Like in my second example in my other comment

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you for the explanation! It works!

Answer (score 1):

event.currentTarget is an object who calls listener so it would be your button, you can remove listener with a help of currentTarget, see next code:

```
btn01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnClickBtn);
btn02.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnClickBtn);

function OnClickBtn(e:Event):void
{
    if ( e.currentTarget.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK) )
    {
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnClickBtn);
    }
}
```